# can you have more than one ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, highcharts

I'm using ajax to extract data from a slow database, this takes upwards of 2.5 seconds. It successfully updates a webpage tag, but when I try to pass it on to a Highcharts gauge chart, unsurprisingly it fails. I thought if I could update a global then pass it on to the chart it would work, it didn't. I tried to delay the chart until the ajax was complete, this failed. 
I think that the problem is I can't seem to be able to update the global.
I would like to post some code, but last time I tried to put HTML on this site It came out wrong.

Yours Simon M.

```
 // JavaScript Document
 // simple ajax to get data
    $(function () 
                {
                $.ajax({
                            url: 'extractLatest.php',   // call php file

                    success: function(datafromphp){ // when it is sucessful
        $( "#latest_mb" ).html(                 // replace html tag <div id="latest_mb"> contents 
                         datafromphp                                    // with whats returned from php
                            );


                                    var position    = "#gauge-chart-a"; // html container name
    // == start of chart == //
        $(function() {
          $(position).highcharts({
              chart: {
                type: 'gauge',
              },
              title: {
               text: 'Last Reading: '+ datafromphp +'mB at '+ msToTime(latest_UTC)
              },

                  pane: {
                startAngle: -150,
                endAngle: 150,
              },
              // the value axis
              yAxis: { // Month
                        // find scale max and min to nearest 10
                min: ((month_lo_mb/10)-0.5).toFixed(0)*10,
                max: ((month_hi_mb/10)+0.5).toFixed(0)*10,
                    title:{text:'mB'}, 

            plotBands: [

                    { // Month
        from: month_lo_mb,
          to: month_hi_mb,
        color: '#9DB6F9'}, // Blue

                    { // Week (Sun thro Sat)
        from: wk_lo_mb,
          to: wk_hi_mb,
        color: '#55BF3B'}, // green

                    { // Day
        from: day_lo_mb,
          to: day_hi_mb,
        color: '#FFFF63'}, // yellow

                    { // Day Avg
                // display day average line in red
        from: day_av_mb-0.125,
          to: day_av_mb+0.125,
        color: '#ff0000'} // red

                ]},
              series: [{ data: [datafromphp] }] // current
            }); // end of chart
        });
    }});
  });
```

this is the closest I get to what's needed

```
<?php
//------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
// Latest
 $latest_mb = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbconnect, "\n"
  ." SELECT UTC,mB \n"
  ." FROM thundersense  \n"
  ." ORDER BY utc DESC LIMIT 1"));

echo $latest_mb[1];
echo sprintf("<h1>Last reading: %1\$.3fmB<br></h1>",$latest_mb[1]);
echo "<h2><i> taken at " . date("H:i:s",$latest_mb[0]) . "</i></h2>";
?>
```

which returns :

```
  < !--
  Start of data extraction
  -- >


982.976
```

Comment: You can use a service like https://jsfiddle.net/ and include the link for code.  However, it is recommended that you still include the relevant portions in your post in case the link expires.

Comment: Why don't you create a chart in `success` callback function? Also you may consider using **promises** mechanism for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thanks for the 'promises', ill look into this more. after a lot of trial and error, I think that my problem is one with extracting the returned data. I see that the returned data looks like [1520280163,979.981], but I can't get it parsed properly.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, its my lack of experience, Ajax snippet

```
     success: function(datafromphp){
     latest_array = JSON.parse(datafromphp);
     );
```

and added to highcharts ...

```
    series: [{ data: [latest_array[1]] }]
```

PHP return

```
echo json_encode($return,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

now it works. Just have to crack the periodic update ...
Yours Simon M.